# Neo4j 3.1.0 apoc.load.csv trouble

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I keep trying to run a `apoc.load.csv` procedure in the newest version of Neo4j 3.1.0, and APOC 3.1.0.3.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.csv("file:///data.csv", 

{sep:",", header:TRUE}) yield map ','
with {map} as map MATCH (t:Tweet{id:toFloat(map.tweet_id)})
SET t.clean_text = map.clean_text,
t.positive_score = toInt(map.nb_positive),
t.negative_score = toInt(map.nb_negative),
t.sentiment_score = toInt(map.score)',
{batchSize:5000, parallel:true})
```

> Error: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by:
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Failed to invoke procedure
>   `apoc.load.csv`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Import from
>   files not enabled, please set apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your
>   neo4j.conf

I have tried just running the `apoc.load.csv` piece and I still get the same error telling me to add the statement to my `neo4j.conf` file, which I have. I've even restarted my computer.

I was able to run this exact same statement successfully in Neo4j 3.0.6 and APOC 3.0.4.1, but it doesn't work since I upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is likely a bug.

If you click on the 'star' in the browser and then under 'System' there is a link to 'Server Configuration'. Run this query to see what Neo4J thinks it has wrt setting.

Part of this looks like:

```
 {
        "isIs": "false ",
        "name": "apoc.export.file.enabled",
        "description": "Configuration attribute",
        "type": "java.lang.String",
        "isReadable": "true",
        "value": "true",
        "isWriteable": "false "
      },
```

which indicates that the file import setting is there and correctly formatted.

The question is then why isn't this being honoured? This is as much as I've been able to determine facing the same problem.